# Cannot add a number in a text field containing html5 number validation using watir/selenium in Ruby

Tags: ruby, html, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

```js
@broswer.text_field(:id => 'mobile1').set "07888888888"
```

```html
<input type="number" class="mobileno required" name="mobile_field" id="mobile1">
```

The first line corresponds to when i am trying to set a number in the text field, but the problem is that when it inserts the number into the text field the zero gets deleted and thus number remaining in the field is just '7888888888' which is not a valid number and thus the validation fails. I have tried using send keys method and even editing the value of the text field but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the input type should not be a number. then the leading zero should be retained. please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Does it work manually when you type in that number? Watir shouldn't be doing anything different.

Comment: Manually it is the same. But when i paste the number manually in the text field. It works perfectly fine. It might be the problem on their end but do we have a work around this problem?

Comment: If the leading zero is removed (via automated or manual entry), then there must be some client-side validation.  In that case, it's intended functionality.  In any event, the described behavior cannot be reproduced using the snippets above (`watir 6.0.2` + chrome 56).

Comment: @orde, My point is that even if it is an html5 Number validation(client side) it should not delete the initial zeros. Assuming its an intended functionality with additional html5 validation, then how should i resolve it using automated tools like watir ?

Comment: You said "manually it is the same." So manually typing it in removes the leading zero, which is not desired behavior, but copy/paste works? If so, you'll need to also do a copy paste using Watir.

Answer (score 0):

as you said manually it removed 0 from text_filed, You might want to try execute_script to check how application behaves.

```
@browser.execute_script("$('text_field#mobile1').val('07888888888')")
```

Answer (score -1):

change the input type to text.

if your database demands an integer, then you'll have to convert the text string to an integer in your controller. The problem here (i'm pretty sure) is that the zero will be eliminated when it is saved to the database.

hope this helps.

*Warning: untested code*

Comment: i cant change it since that component is of third party. Other than changing anything in the text field can this problem be resolved?

Comment: @HassanAbbas im out of answers bro :'(